# How to use onclick function to change ejs variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am creating a web application using Node, Express and ejs. On the same page, I generate a set of buttons (first table below) and a set of corresponding hidden `div`s (second table below). When a button is clicked I want to display the corresponding `div`.

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < stream.length; i++){ %>
<tr>
 <th scope="row"><%= stream[i].streamid %></th>
 <td><%= stream[i].streamname %></td>
 <td><%= stream[i].streamername %></td>
 <td> 
  <button
    class="btn btn-outline-success"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#streamDetailsModal"
    id="detailsstream"
    onclick="<% ctr = i %>"
  >
  Details
  </button>
 </td>
 <td>
  <a
   class="btn btn-outline-danger"
   href="/stream/delete/<%= stream[i].streamid %>"
  >
  ⊖ Remove
  </a>
 </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < stream.length; i++){ %>
<tr>
  <th scope="row"><%= stream[i].streamid %></th>
  <td><%= stream[i].streamname %></td>
  <td><%= stream[i].streamername %></td>
  <td>
   <button
    class="btn btn-outline-success"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#streamDetailsModal"
    id="detailsstream"
    data-ctr="<%= i %>"
   >
   Details
  </button>
 </td>
 <td>
  <a
   class="btn btn-outline-danger"
   href="/stream/delete/<%= stream[i].streamid %>"
  >
  ⊖ Remove
 </a>
</td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

I need the counter in first loop to change while the user clicks on the details button from the second loop.

Comment: There may be a misunderstanding -- EJS runs on the server where there are no buttons. It's a preprocessor that generates HTML. By the time the code runs in the browser where buttons can be clicked, EJS code no longer exists. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish here? Thanks.

Comment: There is a loop which I use to display data from a db and each db item has another set of data linked to it. When ever the user clicks a particular item from list I want a div in the page to show only the data linked to the particular item which the user clicked. Both these lists I am displaying using ejs loops.

Comment: Need to store a relationship between them on the element that gets clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do wish to go with the above logic... the possible way will be to make a ***server call on the button click, compute the value on the server and the re render the page*** on the front end. Browser Javascript cannot change or manipulate the ejs logic or variable. That is done on the node server.

Comment: Is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: Since  u want an "ejs variable" to be modified... im afraid we dont have any other way

Comment: I did a workaround, I just put all the db entries in the html page using ejs and used a bootstrap class to hide them. Using ejs I gave a separate class name to each row. In the details button also I matched gave a data-ctr attribute. Every time user clicks a detail button. I got the value of "data-ctr" using javascript onclick event and using the class name I selected the appropriate tr elements and made them visible.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to implement such functionality is to do something like this instead:

in your first loop generating buttons, add each button a handler that shows the div with some unique id (like `streamDetailsModal12` for button 12); if you use bootstrap or something similar, you don't even have to implement the `handler`

```
  <button
    class="btn btn-outline-success"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#streamDetailsModal<% i %>"
    id="detailsstream"
    onclick="handler(event)"
  >
```

and to each `div` you'd like to show on button click you add corresponding ids:

```
<div id="streamDetailsModal<% i %>"
> some content </div>
```

If you implement `handler` yourself, you have to grab the id from `event.target` (which is your button holding `data-target` attribute with the id you want) and then find the element and toggle it's `display` property or something else you'd like to control visibility.